# Rails 2.3.8: How can I change the asset path for my javascripts, stylesheets and images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

I want to redirect my Rails 2 application ask for javascripts that resides on another server eg `http://asset.example.com/javascripts` how can I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *config/environments/production.rb*:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://asset.example.com"
```

Comment: I like this better, so I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: Thanks I tried it before on development.rb and it didnt work. But it did on production.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following line in environment.rb or specifically production.rb

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = "assets.example.com"
```